# Verify but keep coding hidden

Tags: contract-deployment, clone

Can I verify my Smart Contract on Etherscan but still hide the coding to prevent others from cloning the smart contract?

Comment: No (and what's the point of verifying it in that case anyway?).

Comment: BTW, once you deploy your contract, people can clone it regardless of whether or not it is verified on Etherscan. This verification is just for your transparency towards your users.